# Compile command for adobe air sdk 2.6

Tags: apache-flex, air

I am using adobe air sdk 2.6 and i'm using command line to build my application.What is the command to compile the application.I tried amxmlc its not working.If i see the sdk's bin folder i dont see the amxmlc file there.Any ideas????

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

It's called **mxmlc** (I never heard the name amxmlc). Also make sure you have this executable available in console (add its location to system paths.)

Comment: There is amxmlc,its for air applications and mxmlc for web applications my freind

Comment: Oh yeah, they're the same on my platform (Windows), so I always used mxmlc to compile my AIR applications... Good to know anyway.

Answer (score 0):

mxmlc is to compile Flex for Flash Player (web project)

amxmlc is to compile Flex for AIR (desktop and mobile project)

To create and AIR file you must use adt

Comment: @Snote,You are correct but my question is how to compile mobile apps in air 2.6 sdk,there is no amxmlc in the bin folder.adt is the last step before that i want to compile and get my swf..

Comment: It's in the bin folder of the SDK of Flex. If you using Flash Builder it's \sdks\4.5.0\bin in the Flash Builder folder

Comment: @Snote,Thanks for the quick response,Im not using flash builder i just have the sdk and i want to build it from the cmd line.In Air2.6 sdk there is no amxmlc file inside the bin folder

Comment: I checked it,In air 2.6 sdk there is no amxmlc inside the bin folder.Its available in flex sdk 4.5.0.

Comment: I don't understand. You say you can't find amxmlc in the AIR SDK but you find it in the Flex SDK?

Comment: @Snote,i downloaded the wrong file,Now i downloaded the correct sdk and i found it.Thanks for instant response....